# Rails does not route to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and was going through the tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Section 4.3 is where I'm stuck.

It tells me to configure the routes.rb file by uncommenting `root :to => welcome#index.`

This doesn't seem to work for me.

At the same time, I tried deleting public/index.html but that didn't work either.

`rake routes` gives the following output:

```
C:\Sites\ft-website>rake routes
welcome_index GET /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
     root     /                        welcome#index
```

Any suggestions as to how to get past this block?

EDIT:

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: "welcome#index"
end
```

Comment: What version of ruby and rails are you using? And do you have a `welcome` controller with an `index` action?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Could you please show us your routes.rb?

Comment: Did you restart server after changing `routes.rb`?

Comment: Ruby version 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.13. I have the controllers in place. No error, just not displaying Hello, Rails! Yes, I restarted the server. Will edit the question and add the routes.rb file

Comment: What does it display? What controllers and actions do you have?

Comment: What do you get if you go to `/welcome/index`?

Comment: What does your welcome index action do? Does the log file show it running the index action?

Comment: When I go to `/welcome/index` I get the following error: `ExecJS::RuntimeError in Welcome#index`. Controller is welcome and action is index. Have edited the OP to show routes.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer guys.

The problem was with a coffee script running in the `apps/javascripts` folder.

Deleted the `welcome.js.coffee` file and the routing works now!

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have an `index.html` file in your `[root]/public/` folder.

That was causing this for me.